# React ag grid - bodyScroll event display loader on last row when call API to get more data

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using React ag-grid **Client-side** row model with **onBodyScroll** event to get data. Here, I want to show loader when call the API. I am able to show loader by using **'api.showLoadingOverlay()'** options. But this freeze the whole grid until API return success. So I don't want to freeze the page. Please refer below image, after 99th row showing spinner with 'One moment please'. I want to show loader like this. But this type loader not available **Client-side** row model.

How to achieve this loader for **Client-side** row model type?

I searched lot & checked in ag-grid documentation. Didn't find solution long time. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: No solution for this. Someone please help me to fix this.

Comment: you can add a new row to your rowdata with the spinner + One moment please.. on calling the api, and you can delete this row when you get data back